# Is it optimal to use evaluation expressions within the Elvis operator?

Tags: kotlin, optimization

In Kotlin, if I write:

```
val result = costlyGetter() ?: "default"
```

will `costlyGetter` be called twice?

Otherwise, I will write this:

```
val subresult = costlyGetter()
val result = subresult ?: "default"
```

but this is more verbose.

Comment: Why should it get called twice? It will get called once, and if it returns null then "default" will be stored in result.

Comment: If you add  print statement to costlyGetter you will be able to see

Comment: There is almost certainly something else in your code not in the example that is causing the issues that you are seeing. The first and second code you posted work in the same way, the only difference is, that in the second case you are storing the exact result of costlyGetter() separately.

Comment: A.Steenbergen, I haven't had any issues. I just wanted to know if the first format was optimized. I will check with a print, as matt freake has said.

Comment: It's less "optimized" than "not pessimized".

Comment: I had my doubts since with a ternary operator (which this replaces) you would have to call the method twice or store the subresult. In a naive implementation of Elvis, the method would be called twice.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is not. It is gonna be called single time. Basically both examples are doing same stuff, but second one is creating one more not needed val.

Conclusion is you can stay with the first option. It is fine.

Answer (score 0):

([It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/))

As matt freake suggested, I [checked with a print statement](https://pl.kotl.in/C3B8Ibe6r) and it's only called once. So it's optimized (or, "not pessimized") and we can call `val result = costlyGetter() ?: "default"`.